# Comparison of Rademacher processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose that $T$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f,g$ are two nonnegative functions such that $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Let $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dots,$ be a Rademacher sequence. Does it hold that
$$
\mathbb{E} \sup_{t\in T} \left| \sum_i \epsilon_i f(|t_i|) \right| \leq C\cdot \mathbb{E} \sup_{t\in T} \left| \sum_i \epsilon_i g(|t_i|) \right| \qquad (*)
$$
for some absolute constant $C$?

It looks intuitively true to me but I cannot find it anywhere in the literature. To compare it with the contraction principle that
$$
\mathbb{E} \sup_{t\in T} \left| \sum_i \epsilon_i \alpha_i g(|t_i|) \right| \leq \mathbb{E} \sup_{t\in T} \left| \sum_i \epsilon_i g(|t_i|) \right|, \quad |\alpha_i|\leq 1
$$
it seems that the $\alpha_i$ in my case would depend on $t$ and the proof of the contraction principle above does not seem to go through.

Question: Does (*) hold? Is there a reference in the literature or is there a particularly simple proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$
Letting $a_{it}:=f(|t_i|)$ and $b_{it}:=g(|t_i|)$, rewrite your inequality ($\ast$) as 
\begin{equation}
 E\sup_{t\in T}\Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i a_{it}\Big|\le C\,E\sup_{t\in T}\Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i b_{it}\Big|
\end{equation}
for any natural $N$ and any set $T$, 
with the condition that $0\le a_{it}\le b_{it}$ for all $i,t$.

Let now $T:=2^{[N]}$, the power set of the set $[N]:=\{1,\dots,N\}$. Let $b_{it}:=1$ 
and 
\begin{equation}
 a_{it}:=1_{i\in t}
\end{equation}
for all $i\in[N]$ and $t\in T=2^{[N]}$. Then 
\begin{equation}
 E\sup_{t\in T}\Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i a_{it}\Big|
 \ge E\sum_{i=1}^N\max(0,\ep_i)=N/2, 
\end{equation}
whereas
\begin{equation}
 E\sup_{t\in T}\Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i b_{it}\Big|
 =E\Big|\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i\Big|\le\sqrt{E\Big(\sum_{i=1}^N\ep_i\Big)^2}=\sqrt N. 
\end{equation}

So, your inequality ($\ast$) will fail to hold for any $C>0$ if $N>4C^2$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the contraction principle and was curious whether something like $(*)$ would hold without the contraction assumption. I constructed an example that $(*)$ fails when $C=1$ (take $T=\{(t,\sqrt{1-t^2}): t\in[0,1]\}$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$)  and I am more or less convinced that I shouldn't expect $(*)$ to hold.

Comment: Nice example, thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been able to help.